# DataTables - Filtering and Comparing on Multiple Columns

Tags: javascript, jquery, datatables

Using DataTables plugin. My Table data is correct. I want to filter that data as such:

- Show rows in which column 4 value equals 'Ok' (This is Working)
- Of Those rows show only the rows in which column 7 value is different from column 8 value (This is not working)

(Filter Code)

```
else if (input.value == "IncorrectQuantity") {
                table
                    .columns().search('')
                    .column(4).search('Ok', true, false)
                    .columns([7, 8])
                    .data()
                    .filter(function (value, index) {
                        console.log(value);
                        return value[0] != value[1] ? true : false;
                    })
                    .draw();
            }
```

The output I get from  `console.log(value)` (column7 + column8 data) is:
[image]

So I would want to not display the rows with (17-17 and 15-15). I was expecting `value[0]` to be the first line and `value[1]` the second,
But no, if I do  `console.log(value[0])` I will get `3  and null`. So I have no idea on how to actually compare the column 7 and 8 values.

**Edit**

Following @Frenchy's answer

```
                /*
                    table
                    .columns().search('')                                   //clear other searchs
                    .column(4).search('Ok', true, false)                    //search column 4 value = "Ok"
                    .flatten()                                              //reduces 2D array structures to 1D structure
                    .data()                                                 //provides access to Data
                    .filter(function (value, index) {                       //filter won't actually change which rows are displayed [https://datatables.net/reference/api/filter()]
                        console.log(value.quantity, value.quantityArrival); //value will be an object so i can access it's properties directly
                        return value.quantity != value.quantityArrival;     //value.quantity = Column 7    &&    value.quantity = Column 8
                    })
                    .draw();*/

                //SOLUTION - Custom Filter
                $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
                    function (settings, data, dataIndex) {
                        console.log(data);          //Will print entire row
                        return data[7] != data[8];  //values for column 7 and 8
                    }
                );

                table
                    .columns().search('')                   //clear other searchs
                    .column(4).search('Ok', true, false)    //search column 4 value = "Ok"
                    .draw();

                $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();            //apply custom filter:only display row if column7!=column8
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

following what you say, value is an array and the first value is col7, the second is col8, so, the syntax seems to be:

```
                .columns([7, 8]).flatten()
                .data()
                .filter(function (value, index) {
                    console.log(value[0] != value[1], index);
                    return value[0] != value[1];
                })
```

---

using custom filter

```
else if (input.value == "IncorrectQuantity") {
     
    $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.push(
      function(settings, data, dataIndex) {
        return data[0] != data[1];
      }
    );
    
    table
       .columns().search('')
       .column(4).search('Ok', true, false)
       .columns([7, 8]).flatten()
       .data()
       .draw();

  $.fn.dataTable.ext.search.pop();
```

Comment: value[index][0] is undefined. Also I would like to point that value[0] has actually both values from column 7 and 8 (row 0), and value [1] from row 1 and so on. But  I don´t know how to compare the values if they are both inside value[n]. Seems DataTables would have something to iterate the data

Comment: @HenriquePombo i haveadded flatten(), could you try?

Comment: i am not sure you could redraw the datatable you have to use a custom filter

Comment: Custom Filter did the job. Regarding `.filter(){}` after `flatten`, it's possible to access value's properties directly e.g: value.quantity (my column7); but I have no ideia how to use that to actually change the display the data in the table (without the custom filter, that is). I have edited my answer to apply the help you provided (deleting some useless stuff I had added before), Thank You for the help

Comment: glad to help, so i have discovered flatten() too!! but you have right you could avoid with the custom filter